# creating table and adding data using pug(jade) in express

Tags: express, pug

I am creating a table in express using jade. I am not able to to enter the values in table. I am handling a product route.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    home = require('./routes/home.js');

var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use('/home', home);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Access through http://localhost:3000/');
```

**home.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home/index', { id:'1',name:'hp', quantity:'3'},{ id:'2',name:'dell', quantity:'2'},{ id:'3',name:'sony', quantity:'5'});

});
module.exports = router;
```

**index.jade**

```
doctype
html
  head
    title=title
  body
    h3 Comments
    table
      tr
        th Id
        th Name
        th Quantity
      each item in item
         tr
            td #{item.id}
            td #{item.name}
            td #{item.quantity}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass local variables to Pug in a single object. Writing the item objects as an array will help with iterating over it. Try this instead in your `home.js`:

```
res.render('home/index', {
    items: [
        { id:'1', name:'hp',   quantity:'3' },
        { id:'2', name:'dell', quantity:'2' },
        { id:'3', name:'sony', quantity:'5' }
    ]
});
```

Then in your Pug, it's important to use different variable names for the two items in your `each` loop ("item" vs "items"):

```
each item in items
    tr
        td #{item.id}
        td #{item.name}
        td #{item.quantity}
```